# Date Formatting in SQL for weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select
[fa] as 'CouponName',
[fb] as 'Store',
[fc] as 'DateTime',
[fd] as 'PLU',
[fe] as 'QTY'
FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
where [fd] = '00milecard' and [fc] >= dateadd(dd, -70, getdate()),
Order By [fb]
```

This produces:

```
CouponName************Store***DateTime*********************PLU**************QTY
CPN: MILE CARD $5***    747***  2020-01-10 14:57:26.060***  00MILECARD***   1.0000
CPN: MILE CARD $5***    747***  2020-01-10 19:21:12.763***  00MILECARD***   1.0000
CPN: MILE CARD $5***    747***  2020-01-11 18:19:01.093***  00MILECARD***   1.0000
CPN: MILE CARD $5***    747***  2020-01-12 17:11:29.610***  00MILECARD***   1.0000
CPN: MILE CARD $5***    747***  2020-01-12 15:33:31.747***  00MILECARD***   1.0000
CPN: MILE CARD $5***    747***  2020-01-13 13:11:58.243***  00MILECARD***   1.0000
CPN: MILE CARD $5***    747***  2020-01-08 16:45:41.070***  00MILECARD***   1.0000
CPN: MILE CARD $5***    747***  2020-01-03 18:11:12.050***  00MILECARD***   1.0000
CPN: MILE CARD $5***    748***  2020-01-11 15:12:13.370***  00MILECARD***   1.0000
CPN: MILE CARD $5***    748***  2020-01-10 11:59:28.517***  00MILECARD***   1.0000
CPN: MILE CARD $5***    748***  2019-12-26 08:17:40.420***  00MILECARD***   1.0000
CPN: MILE CARD $5***    748***  2019-12-26 15:39:31.900***  00MILECARD***   1.0000
CPN: MILE CARD $5***    748***  2019-12-27 14:59:12.890***  00MILECARD***   1.0000
CPN: MILE CARD $5***    750***  2020-01-04 19:08:45.337***  00MILECARD***   1.0000
CPN: MILE CARD $5***    750***  2020-01-08 06:23:59.963***  00MILECARD***   1.0000
```

I need this to sum the qty in a week's time span, per store number, and run for a period of 10 weeks(70 days).
Our week is a Monday - Sunday.
I think a "DATEDIFF" will do this, but I do not have any experience with this formatter.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will do what you want:

```
select min(fc0), fb, sum(fe)
from [database].[dbo].[table]
where [f01] = '00milecard' and
      datediff(week, fc, getdate()) <= 10
group by datediff(week, fc, getdate()), fb
Order By [fb]
```

Comment: I'd like to see an example that customizes which day starts the week.